# Default Password of CouchDB Server (Fauxton UI)

Tags: couchdb, fauxton

I am new to couchDB world after installing its latest version I am getting login window. I don't know what is default username and password.

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally, when you install a fresh CouchDB, you have an admin party. This mean you don't need to authenticate to interact with Fauxton.

If you don't know the password, you can always add an admin into the local.ini file. This file should be in a folder similar to /couchdb/var/config/local.ini

Comment: Hello Alexis, I have installed couchDB through dmg and getting this login window when start my server.I am also not able to locate local.ini file

Comment: dmg? are you installing in a macOS? In this case the package is a zip are you downloading the dmg from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am installing it on macOS and I have downloaded it from the official website of couchDB (http://couchdb.apache.org/)

Comment: Here are the install instructions for Mac: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/mac.html — they are INCORRECT — I'm also getting blocked b/c I don't have an admin username and password. There's no default ini file either. Three years later and there's still no answer to this question...

Answer (score 2):

To verify if you already have and admin user configured you should check the local.ini config file in CouchDB.

In macOS for default package it should be located here:
~/Library/Preferences/couchdb2-local.ini

Edit the local.ini and check if there is an [admins] section on it. Add an admin user or replace the existing password

```
[admins]
admin=<your-new-pass>
```

Restart couchdb, the pass will be hashed in the file and you can log in with the new admin user.

Comment: new installs on Mac don't have an ini file, and the folder is empty. This is incorrect

Comment: For others stumbling across this answer: to restart couchdb, type: `/etc/init.d/couchdb restart` – you can also restart the service: `sudo service couchdb restart`

Comment: This is for a linux system, the answer is focused on a macOS